# ASP.NET Load Balancing on IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis, load, load-balancing, arr

I have two application servers(IIS, ASP.NET), they are connected by Ethernet, one of them has a dedicated IP address. Each of them receives data, makes calculations, and then sends the response back. The load on them will be small, about 30-40 users. 
So, I have two questions. 
IIS plugin Application Request Routing is well suited for this configuration? Can I use a balancer on one of the compute servers or is it better to dedicate a separate machine for it?

Comment: Windows load balancing services or ARR are both OK.

Comment: Thnaks for replay! I installed arr and created a server farm, tests from monitoring and managment showed pass for URL. But I had a problem with access to write to the disk in my web app - access denied for App_Data folder. Where i can fix it?